# Azure Active Directory B2C with Passport.js error "Cannot get aad federation metadata" error

Tags: node.js, passport.js, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, passport-azure-ad

I'm trying to implement customer-facing authentication for my Node.js web app using Passport.js and Azure Active Directory B2C with the OpenID Connect strategy.

I have followed the README instructions from the official GitHub page and studied the source code of the official sample apps, but they seem to be incomplete and/or out of date, as agreed by various threads online.

After piecing together various tips from around the web, I have crossed many bridges, but reached an impasse with the following error:

`cannot get AAD Federation metadata from endpoint you specified`.

There is a ton of configuration required for AAD authentication, so I will note some important values:

- `policyName`: This is `b2c_1_signin`, just like I have configured in the Azure portal.
- `identityMetadata`: I'm using a tenant-specific, v2.0 endpoint. I added `?p=b2c_1_signin` to inject the policy name.
- `responseType`: `id_token`
- `redirectUrl`: This is my localhost and port, as configured in Azure. `allowHttpForRedirectUrl` is set to `true`. (This works for non-prod environments.)
- `isB2C`: `true`

Comment: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-nodejs-webapi/issues/3#issuecomment-511924347. Is it helpful?

Answer (score 10):

For B2C, you need to set `validateIssuer: false`. For non-common endpoint, we use the issuer from the metadata that is returned from AAD, for B2C, passport.authenticate cannot grab the `issuer` value from the metadata. For B2C, passport uses the TenantId to handle validation, so that must be provided, which would be part of the `identityMetadata`.

Also, the `identityMetadata` should have this format:

`identityMetadata: "https://" + b2cDomainHost + "/" + tenantIdGuid + "/" + policyName + "/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration/"`

I don't think passport is set up to handle this format for the metadata url -> `?p=b2c_1_signin`

You can try [this node.js sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-nodejs-webapi/blob/master/index.js#L12), and use your own values, which will call into the passport.js library.

Example:

```
var clientID = "93733604-cc77-4a3c-a604-87084dd55348";
var b2cDomainHost = "fabrikamb2c.b2clogin.com";
var tenantIdGuid = "775527ff-9a37-4307-8b3d-cc311f58d925";
var policyName = "B2C_1_SUSI";
var options = {
    identityMetadata: "https://" + b2cDomainHost + "/" + tenantIdGuid + "/" + policyName + "/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration/",

    clientID: clientID,
    policyName: policyName,
    isB2C: true,
    validateIssuer: false,
    loggingLevel: 'info',
    loggingNoPII: false,
    passReqToCallback: false
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Jenny. Following this formula, I tried using the URL:  
 `https://<MY_SUBDOMAIN>.b2clogin.com/<MY_TENANT_ID>/<MY_POLICY>/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`.  
I now get the following error:  

`authentication failed due to: invalid policy`

What is a "policy" exactly, and where is it configured? Is this the same as a "user flow"? Is this something that I am supposed to configure, or is it a fixed property? Thanks again.

Comment: One thing that makes B2C so frustrating is the inconsistent naming of resources. For example, a "policy" is also referred to as a "user flow" interchangeably throughout the official Microsoft docs (ex. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-overview), yet I can't find the word "policy" anywhere within the Azure portal.

Comment: @johnothegrouch a user flow enables the developer to control behaviors in your app through configuration and custom policies are user flows which have been fully customized. We do use the two interchangeably, which is confusing, but just think of them as the same. Here's a [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-overview) that might help.

Comment: @johnothegrouch Once you have an AAD subscription, you can create an AAD B2C tenant, and there you will manage the policies and applications. See this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant). If you need help send me an email.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have a policy called `b2c_1_signin`, which has sign up and sign in priveleges. Using this value in the template above, I get the error `invalid policy`. I'll send an email, thank you.

Comment: @johnothegrouch sounds good. BTW, in the portal, you can run the policy there and make sure it's set up correctly on the server side. I can't post an image here, but under the policy in the portal, there is an arrow at the top that says "run now". click there and it will display that policy's UI.